# Regex to replace a combination of number(digits/word) and a word

Tags: php, jquery, regex

I use following code to replace a number and string to a replacement text

```
var rule = (\d+\s((apple\b|apples\b|Apple\b|Apples\b)+))
var search_regexp = new RegExp(rule, "ig");
return masterstring.replace(search_regexp,replacetext);
```

- input string : `10 apples are better than 100 pears`
- replacement: `10 Oranges`
- Result: `10 Oranges are better than 100 pears`

How is it possible to have a regular expression for handling `10 apples` and `Ten apples`? Say one to identify

```
 (a number in digits or word)+space+(a case insensitive word)
```

and replace this with 10 Oranges both using jQuery and php?

Comment: Group the word and the number as alterations?

Comment: Unless you iterate the numbers inside the regex, *one by one* it's impossible.

Comment: Also, note that since you're using the `i` modifier, `(\d+\s((apple\b|apples\b|Apple\b|Apples\b)+))` == `(\d+\s((apples?\b)+))`

Comment: `Three hundred thousand, four hundred and twenty-eight apples` are better than 100 pears. Replacement `300,428 Oranges` are better than 100 pears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specifically only want to match valid number 'words' you would have to literally include in your regex all the numbers you want to include.

`(one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten)` etc.

This could be improved by combining words that start with the same letter:

`(one|t(wo|hree|en)|f(our|ive)|s(ix|even)|eight|nine)`

You can then include your `\d+` as your first option:

`(\d+|one|t(wo|hree|en)|f(our|ive)|s(ix|even)|eight|nine)`

As some said in the comments you are using the case insensitive modifier, so I have done all lower case)

Note that if you want to go beyond ten this will become quite long, and hard to make efficient, I've had a quick go, and created a beast of a regex, I have not tried to optimise too much..

```
(?:
  \d+
  |t(?:en|hirteen)
  |eleven
  |twelve
  |fifteen
  |(?:
    (?:twenty|thirty|fourty|fifty|sixty|seventy|eighty|ninety)
    (?:[ -](?:one|t(?:wo|hree)|f(?:our|ive)|s(?:ix|even)|eight|nine))?
  )
  |(?:one|t(?:wo|hree)|f(?:our(?:teen)?|ive)|s(?:ix|even)(?:teen)?|eight(?:een)?|nine(?:teen)?)
)[ ]apples?
```

I have spread this over several lines and added the 'x' modifier in the online example - this makes it much easier to read, this works in PHP but not in javascript, you would have to remove the newlines/whitespace to use in JS)
[https://regex101.com/r/zDYme7/1](See working example online here)

Its also worth mentioning that doing this in regex may not be the best way - a string tokenizer would involve a lot less cpu time, but would involve more code.

One example of a tokenizer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tokenize-text

Comment: I'm trying this one now. Thank you for pointing out on case insensitivity. Although I would the plural as well as singular(apple).